# Pathos multiprocessing pipe and queue on windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, pathos

I'm trying to use the [`pathos`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) library to replace the builtin multiprocessing library, but am having difficulty using either pipes or queues on windows. Here's a representative example:

```
from pathos.helpers import mp
#import multiprocessing as mp

def f(pipe, queue):
    if sys.gettrace():
        print 'Debug mode. About to crash'
    else:
        print 'Execute mode'
    pipe.send('pipe')
    queue.put('queue')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()

    to_child, to_self = mp.Pipe()
    queue = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(to_child, queue))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

`pipe.send('pipe')` raises `IOError: (6, 'The handle is invalid')` and `queue.put('queue')` raises `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied`. Both work correctly using the vanilla multiprocessing module.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**:
This crash only occurs when I'm trying to debug child processes (I use [WingIDE](https://wingware.com/)). I can accurately predict the crash by checking `sys.gettrace()`, as above.

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  I just tried your code verbatim on a mac, and it works.  I don't normally run on windows, but I believe that on windows, you generally have to do `mp.freeze_support()` as the first line of the `__main__` block.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcKerns (and thanks for the library). Unfortunately I get the same behaviour with `mp.freeze_support()`, as edited above. Grr windows.

Comment: Hmm, I'll give it a try on windows when I can.  In the meantime… do you have a C-compiler? Note that `multiprocess` requires a C-compiler to build correctly -- and if you don't have one, the build doesn't fail, it defaults to `_multiprocessing` which is the C-library portion from the standard library.  It's functional for many cases, but fails in other cases.. so you might want to check your build.  What happens when you `import _multiprocess`?

Comment: @MikeMcKerns, I've just discovered that this behaviour only occurs when my IDE ([Wing](https://wingware.com/)) is set to debug child processes, see edit. I'm not actually sure if I have a c compiler. I'm using mingw for a shell, but I'm not sure if it's g++ works with pip by default. `import _multiprocess` succeeds... which means pathos did not build its own `multiprocess`?

Comment: Interesting.  The import succeeding means that it used the mingw's gcc compiler.  I think that's fine… however, building on mingw is untested.

Comment: `multiprocessing` (and thus `multiprocess`, and thus `pathos`) can demonstrate some issues when dealing with IDEs… and worse still debuggers in IDEs.  So a crash or a hang doesn't surprise me under the circumstances you are describing.  Does vanilla `multiprocessing` experience the same issues under the same circumstances?

Comment: Vanilla `multiprocessing`'s pipe and queue do not encounter errors. After discussion with the WingIDE authors, I believe I understand why: Wing's child process debugging works by monkeypatching the `multiprocessing` module. I guess Wing doesn't know about `pathos`, and `pathos` doesn't know about Wing, so it makes sense that this wouldn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That makes sense.  You should post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue arises when [Wing](https://wingware.com) IDE is set to debug child processes. As I understand it, wing enables child process debugging by inserting itself between parent and child processes (which means that 'child' processes are now actually the grandchildren of the parent process). On windows, this is made possible by monkeypatching `multiprocessing` to cause Popen to set the 'inheritable' flag to `True` when calling `duplicate()` on handles.

Without the `inheritable` setting, grandchild processes cannot access the handles, and hence the exceptions above are raised.

It seems likely that a similar monkey patch could be applied to `pathos`'s `helpers.mp` module to allow wing to debug child processes with `pathos`.

Comment: With thanks to [Mike McKerns](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2379433/mike-mckerns) and [Stephan Diebel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/698685/stephan-deibel) for helping me understand this.

Comment: You could copy the `wing` monkeypatch file and apply it to `multiprocess` (just by changing the spelling slightly). You might have to also monkey with your `PYTHONPATH` (or `path` from python). If you want the patch to be applied otherwise, it'd have to be in `wing`.